# check if RenderFragment is empty

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, blazor

Is there a way to check if RenderFragment is empty?

For example, in the code below, `MyComp` shows the `Detail` if `Open` is true & you can toggle `Open` by clicking on the header. Now If there's no header, I'd like the `Detail` fragment to always be open.  This would be easy if there was a property like `HeaderTitle.IsEmpty`.

```
    <MyComp Open="false">
        <HeaderTitle>
             @if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(hdr)) {
                 ...
                <div class="flex-grow"> @hdr </div>
            }
        </HeaderTitle>
        <Detail>
            ...
        </Detail>
   </MyComp>
```

**Edit**

For further discussion I added a feature request [here](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/10270).

Comment: would it be possible to have the model implement this check behaviour instead?  keep the view 'dumb' as possible is better imho

Comment: A RenderFragment is a Delegate, so you would have to run it ...  But you can't redirect the output, afaik.

Comment: @JohnB I have added a ShowHeader property in the mean time.  But this doesn't make MyComp less smart & kinda complicates MyComp's parent...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Old question, but as it is unanswered and getting upvotes....

A RenderFragment is a code method, not a container, so it does not have an `Empty` state.
It can be null - which is equivalent to empty in the sense that it will produce no rendered output.

In the context of this question, you can effectively treat `null` as `Empty` - and simply have a method in your code

```cs
bool HeaderTitleIsEmpty => HeaderTitle is null;
```

Comment: When `String.IsNullOrEmpty(hdr)` then MyComp gets an _empty_ HeaderTitle that _is not_ `null`.

Comment: Do you though? depends on how the component is implemented - we can't see that

Comment: e.g. if the component renders a div with the HeaderTitle inside it, it is not empty - it has the div

Comment: Does this work with generic `[Parameter] public RenderFragment<TItem> CustomTemplate { get; set; }`? For me it looks like not working...